# Clicking link on page 1 takes you to page 2 and chages content in iFrame

Tags: php, jquery, html

Let's presume I have a link in my page 1. After clicking on it, I want to navigate to page 2, where I have an iFrame and load some content (page3) I specify in page 1. Any kind of advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: In page A i have
<a href="pageB(what to load into frame)" target="frame">LINK</a>
But this isn't working. it always opens a new page with pageB
How to specifiy to the browser i want to open pageB in the page with the frame (pageC)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a page 1 with different links and all of them take you to page 2, and the only thing you want to change when clicking the different links is the content of the iFrame, you could use POST or GET (depending of what information you are passing, take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Page 1:

```
<a href="page2.php?link=1">page2, content one</a>
<a href="page2.php?link=2">page2, content two</a>
```

And then on page 2:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['link'] == 1) {
$iFrameURL = "url1.html";
} else {
$iFrameURL = "url2.html";
}
?>
<html>
...
 <iframe src="<?php echo $iFrameURL ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: But wouldn't that destroy the iFrame? Because i'm also using it in page 2 as a standard iFrame for loading content when clicking on links in page 2
But your idea is great and it gave me a place to start with!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: BTW, in the case you have a lot of different links you should use [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead of the `if` statement. Using `switch` you can also add a default value to `$iFrameURL` which could be displayed if `page2` isn't called from a link from `page1`. EDIT: If this resolves you question please mark my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Need some more rep for your answer to be marked, but i already selected it as the answer. This worked like a charm with everything from link styling to iFrame content. Best answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is incredibly vague.

If you wish to make a link go to the next page it's as simple as using the `href=""` property like so:

```
<a href="page2.html" >Link Title</a>
```

Then is you have the iframe in page 2 already it'll load, just make sure your root path to page2.html is correct in the href section.

For  more conclusive or indepth answers then rewrite your question with code examples of your attempts and clearer description of your goal. What you want to achieve can easily be found with a quick google